# Openshift installation on Ubuntu fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift, amazon-route53, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

I am trying to install openshift on Ubuntu by following the following article
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/installing/installing_aws/installing-aws-default.html#installing-aws-default
However, I am stuck at this command `./openshift-install create cluster --dir=<installation_directory> \ 
    --log-level=info`

**This is the error I am receiving.**

```
atest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html ********************************************************************INFO Creating infrastructure resources...         **********************************************************************************************************************************************************ERROR                                              ******************************************ERROR Error: [ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: [Tried to create resource record set [name='api.openshift.company_name.io.', type='A'] but it already exists] *****************************ERROR **status code: 400, request id: 872e5e4c-9511-474f-9c39-5e016a9622fc **************************ERROR                                              **************************************************ERROR   on ../../tmp/openshift-install-276450429/route53/base.tf line 23, in resource "aws_route53_record" "api_external": *******************************************************************************ERROR   23: resource "aws_route53_record" "api_external" { ******************************************ERROR                                              **************************************************ERROR                                              **************************************************ERROR                                              **************************************************ERROR Error: Error creating EIP: AddressLimitExceeded: The maximum number of addresses has been reached. *************************************************************************************************ERROR **status code: 400, request id: 376a4c5e-e2b6-4af7-8404-4be0fb3fa511 **************************ERROR                                              **************************************************ERROR   on ../../tmp/openshift-install-276450429/vpc/vpc-public.tf line 60, in resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip": *********************************************************************************************ERROR   60: resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip" {         **************************************************ERROR                                              **************************************************ERROR                                              *******************************************
ERROR
ERROR Error: Error creating EIP: AddressLimitExceeded: The maximum number of addresses has been reached.
ERROR   status code: 400, request id: bfa6cf06-2388-4901-a7c0-c9d9a19561c9
ERROR
ERROR   on ../../tmp/openshift-install-276450429/vpc/vpc-public.tf line 60, in resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip":
ERROR   60: resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip" {
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR Error: Error creating EIP: AddressLimitExceeded: The maximum number of addresses has been reached.
ERROR   status code: 400, request id: 30f575a5-d97e-4be2-9c53-2dba0e384def
ERROR
ERROR   on ../../tmp/openshift-install-276450429/vpc/vpc-public.tf line 60, in resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip":
ERROR   60: resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip" {
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR Error: Error creating EIP: AddressLimitExceeded: The maximum number of addresses has been reached.
ERROR   status code: 400, request id: 9e16410c-ef84-4dde-86
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit an AWS service limit. AWS is returning an error:

```
ERROR Error: Error creating EIP: AddressLimitExceeded: The maximum number of addresses has been reached.
ERROR
```

Amazon only allows 5 EIPs per region, when in a VPC. This is both unassociated and associated ones.

> Elastic IP Addresses. Elastic IP addresses per Region for EC2-VPC. 5. This is the limit for the number of Elastic IP addresses for use in EC2-VPC. For Elastic IP addresses for EC2-Classic, see Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2).

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

You may be able to request an increase in this service limit. See 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/manage-service-limits/